# How to do Social Login (Facebook,Google,LInkedin and Github) in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]

### App.module.ts

```
const config = new AuthServiceConfig(
[
{id:GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
provider:new GoogleLoginProvider('358720783918-g6gv4vsabi786qcj0sbvkm2v36totpio.apps.googleusercontent.com')

},
{id:FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
provider:new FacebookLoginProvider('2892581370768110')
},
 {id:LinkedinLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
provider:new LinkedinLoginProvider('77emt6ok070g9q')
// provider:new LinkedinLoginProvider('5bfd1b994c4d8f4948eef894')
  } 
 ]
  );
       export function provideConfig(){
       return config;
       }
```

### app.component.ts

```
 linkedinLogin(){
  this.social.signIn(LinkedinLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then((userData) =>{
 this.user = userData;
console.log("Linked in:"+this.user);
 })
```

ReferenceError: IN is not defined. Please help me how to fix this error??

Comment: post some code  !

Comment: @ Sachila Ranawaka Please check i have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have some typo in your code, maybe you are calling IN.something, and IN is not a valid variable or function, it's not defined.

Search all your code for the text 'IN' using case sensitive, you might found some place where you are calling it by mistake.